# Pentaho connection error connecting to database

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I am getting the below error while connecting. I am able to ping the server
but connection error coming.

```
error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.driver) 
access denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost' (using password: yes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong password, wrong user or insuficient privileges.